# How to refer to an extension method of a generic class in XML comments

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, xml-comments

What is the proper XML-comment syntax to refer to the SingleOrDefault extension method on the IEnumerable interface?

My latest attempt is:

```
<see cref="IEnumerable{T}.SingleOrDefault{T}()"/>
```

The warning is:

> XML comment on 'yourMethod' has cref attribute 'IEnumerable.SingleOrDefault()' that could not be resolved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close. The extension method belongs to the `Enumerable` class. Try:

```
<see cref="Enumerable.SingleOrDefault{TSource}(IEnumerable{TSource})"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried all sorts of stuff, and it was getting quite annoying :)  I hate that it was a simple oversight on my part, but I'm glad it's done.